# What is the theory of the ram's horn yoke?

Tags: aircraft-design, cockpit

Embraer tend to use a Ram's Horn yoke in the Phenom and many of their RJ aircraft:

[image: Embraer Phenom 300 Cockpit]

And Cessna uses a more standard yoke with vertical sides:

[image: Cessna CJ3 Cockpit]

What is Embraer's reasoning for the Ram's Horn Yoke? Are there advantages?

Comment: It was used on Concorde also.